# Remove first part of a string based on unique tag

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to remove everything between `<p class="releaseDateline">SOME TEXT</p>`. The good news is that the string always uses `<p class="releaseDateline">SOME TEXT</p>` - the bad news is that the text within that p tag always changes.

What I am looking for is to not only remove the text between `<p class="releaseDateline"></p>` but also the complete `<p class="releaseDateline"></p>` section.

Example String:

```
<p class="releaseDateline">New York, NY  August 19, 2013 </p><p>Kaminski Auctions is pleased to announce the addition of Sheri Mason to our team of expert appraisers.</p>
```

What I am looking for is to get this result:

```
<p>Kaminski Auctions is pleased to announce the addition of Sheri Mason to our team of expert appraisers.</p>
```

That said, if my string contains the `<p class="releaseDateline"></p>` then I would like to have it removed, no matter what text is within the tags, but keep everything else in tact.

I am still pretty new to PHP as I just do some small jobs for friends now and then, so I tried some stuff with str_replace but since the content within the element is never the same, I am having issues understanding how I would go from there.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: `preg_replace()` should be enough, or it can even be done with plain string functions.

Comment: This can be done using regular expressions.  It's a powerful way to search (and replace) text with flexible rules.  Downside is that it can be tricky at the start, but it's very much worth learning.  A good regular expression can move mountains (of text).  I even use them outside of program code to exit text in large text documents with Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this (where `$str` holds your content):

```
preg_replace('/<p class="releaseDateline">(.*)</p>/g', '', $str);
```

Have a look here:  http://regexr.com?360sd

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myString = '<p class="releaseDateline">New York, NY  August 19, 2013 </p><p>Kaminski Auctions is pleased to announce the addition of Sheri Mason to our team of expert appraisers.</p>';
$tab1 = explode('<p class="releaseDateline">', $myString);
if(isset($tab1[1])){
  $tab2 = explode('</p>', $tab1[1]);
  $myString = $tab2[1];
}
echo $myString;
?>
```

Comment: This works nicely, except that it cuts the text after the second `</p>` Any idea how to change it so it does not cut the string if it contains more than one `</p>`?